# Android one line Toast

Tags: java, android

I want to make a Toast with Gravity set to TOP, I wrote this code

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0).show();
```

But to my surprise Android Studio gives me an error.
Please take a look here [image]

After consulting the Documentation I came up with this code, which works perfectly fine

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
toast.show();
```

Also working is

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Why does this work and my first code doesn't? What's the difference?

EDIT ok from the answers a gathered, that setGravity returns void, but why is that? Isn't

```
hello = somthg;
hello.world();
```

the same as

```
somthg.world();
```

?!

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of the error

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/wMJNdy8w/Unbenannt-1.png

Comment: please add that in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toast.setGravity()` sadly does not return the Toast:

```
public static void setGravity(...)
```

In your first Toast, you are trying to `show()` void which is impossible.

You must do it separately as you showed in your question. Every time you do a `.something()` you are using the output of the previous `.something()` rather than the original output of `makeText(...)` in this example.

Comment: That doesn't work either, it also gives me "Incompatible Types"

Comment: "you are using the output of the previous" that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The method `setGravity()` of the class `Toast()` returns `void` and not a `Toast` object. 
This is its signature:

```
public void setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

so you can't call `show()`. 
But this:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
```

is a valid call and then you call `show()` on the Toast object:

```
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot chain just because you want, but only when all methods return required type for chaining. In your case `setGravity()` is void (which is pretty dumb):

```
public void setGravity (int gravity, 
            int xOffset, 
            int yOffset)
```

In general you should always Read The Funny Manual if in dobuts